# Логика работы абстрактного синтаксического дерева

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, синтаксический-анализ

#### Цель

Создать простой математический ЯП (строчный калькулятор).

#### Описание

Знаю, что создание ЯП делят на 3 основных и 2 дополнительных этапа. Основные:

- Lexer - Читает код и разбирает его на токены.
- Parser - Создается абстрактное синтаксическое дерево из полученных токенов.
- Evaluator - Читает и выполняет вышеупомянутое дерево.

---

Первую часть сделал. Мой lexer понимает цифры, операторы `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, и скобки.
Собственно вот он - [eccs0103.github.io/AEL/](https://eccs0103.github.io/AEL/pages/main.html?expression=(1.2%20+%202.8)%20/%200.5) (Arithmetic Extended Language).

---

Дальше идет создание АСД.

[image]

То есть по логике у нас должен быть некий класс `Operation`, который будет иметь левые и правые стороны:

```js
class Operation {
  constructor(operator, left, right) {
    this.operator = operator;
    this.left = left;
    this.right = right;
  }
  operator;
  left;
  right;
}
```

И надо будет описать все эти выражения с помощью него.

```js
const result = new Operation(`/`, new Operation(`+`, 1.2, 2.8), 0.5);
```

Только у меня не получается придумать логику, как все это реализовать. Если даже в линейных
выражениях (выражения без скобок - `1 + 2 / 3`) получается писать какой-то алгоритм, то в некоторых выражениях ничего не получается.
Как программа должна в зависимости от типа скобки менять очередь операций? Как должна проверять синтаксис и кидать ошибки? Как правильно писать эту логику в конце концов?

#### Вопрос

Вот, прошу помочь с логикой данной задачи.

#### Дополнительно

Код lexer-а можете найти [тут](https://github.com/eccs0103/AEL/blob/main/scripts/structure.js), класс `Interpreter`, функция `tokenize`.

Comment: _Дальше идет создание АСД. Прочитал — какие есть, какие советуют. Выбрал вот такой._ - а какие еще есть?

Comment: @Grundy говорят ещё о [форме Бэкуса - Наура](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0) и есть ещё [расширенная версия этой формы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%91%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B0_%E2%80%94_%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0).

Comment: @Grundy я понял как они работают, но написать такую логику даже не пробовал. :)

Comment: эмм, это просто способы записи. Это не является видом дерева

Comment: вторая ссылка битая

Comment: @Grundy уже работает. Я вас понял. Убрал лишние строки.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142307/discussion-between-grundy-and-eccs0103).